# Parse decimal number using Cuerdas in a ClojureScript program

Tags: parsing, floating-point, numbers, decimal, clojurescript

I am using [Cuerdas library](https://github.com/funcool/cuerdas) in a
ClojureScript program to parse floating point numbers. Sometimes the input from
a user is missing the integral part, like `.1` for `0.1`. I need to handle this.
But I ran into strange results when comparing the parsed numbers:

```
(= 0.1 (parse-number "0.1"))
;; => true

(= .1 (parse-number "0.1"))
;; => true

(= 0.1 (parse-number ".1"))
;; => false

(= .1 (parse-number ".1"))
;; => false
```

The last two results above are surprising to me. When comparing literal number I
get the expected result:

```
(= 0 .0)
;; => true
```

The strange behavior is also visible when I just parse the decimal number without integer
part, like here:

```
(parse-number ".1")
;; => .1

.1
;; => 0.1
```

I found out that I can use `js/parseFloat` to get what I want, but I'm curious
what is the reason for this behavior when using Cuerdas? What is this `.1` value
and how is it different than `0.1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`parse-number`](https://github.com/funcool/cuerdas/blob/9fc1062bb348234e4cfc36babf51b13fd572d7b7/src/cuerdas/core.cljc#L637) source looked like this:

```clj
(defn parse-number
  "General purpose function for parse number like
  string to number. It works with both integers
  and floats."
  [s]
  (if (nil? s)
    #?(:cljs js/NaN :clj Double/NaN)
    (if (numeric? s)
      (edn/read-string s)
      #?(:cljs js/NaN :clj Double/NaN))))
```

Both `".1"` and `"0.1"` are considered to be [`numeric?`](https://github.com/funcool/cuerdas/blob/9fc1062bb348234e4cfc36babf51b13fd572d7b7/src/cuerdas/core.cljc#L231) (was implemented in cuerdas by a regex check):

```sh
cljs.user=> (def re #"^[+-]?([0-9]*\.?[0-9]+|[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*)([eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?$")
#'cljs.user/re
cljs.user=> (boolean (re-matches re "0.1"))
true
cljs.user=> (boolean (re-matches re ".1"))
true
```

so they will be read by [`cljs.reader/read-string`](https://cljs.github.io/api/cljs.reader/read-string).

When reading the string `"0.1"` the return type is a `js/Number`, but `".1"` is of type `cljs.core/Symbol`:

```sh
cljs.user=> (cljs.reader/read-string ".1")
.1
cljs.user=> (cljs.reader/read-string "0.1")
0.1
cljs.user=> (type (cljs.reader/read-string "0.1"))
#object[Number]
cljs.user=> (type (cljs.reader/read-string ".1"))
cljs.core/Symbol
```

So although it looks like it correctly parsed the .1 it actually turned it into a symbol. The symbol `.1` is not equal to the number `.1`.

Note that `parse-number` is [no longer available in newer versions](https://github.com/funcool/cuerdas/issues/78) of cuerdas because it "is a string manipulation library not a numbers parsing library".

Answer (score 0):

I have some [numeric parsing functions](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/0.9.214/api/tupelo.parse#parse-int) that work for both CLJ and CLJS.  From the unit tests, we have

The headers:

```
(ns tst.tupelo.parse
  ;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ;   https://code.thheller.com/blog/shadow-cljs/2019/10/12/clojurescript-macros.html
  ;   http://blog.fikesfarm.com/posts/2015-12-18-clojurescript-macro-tower-and-loop.html
  #?(:cljs (:require-macros
             [tupelo.misc]
             [tupelo.testy]))
  (:require
    [clojure.test] ; sometimes this is required - not sure why
    [tupelo.parse :as tpar]
    [tupelo.misc :as misc]
    [tupelo.core :as t :refer [spy spyx spyxx spyx-pretty]]
    [tupelo.testy :refer [deftest testing is dotest isnt is= isnt= is-set= is-nonblank=
                          throws? throws-not? define-fixture]])
  #?(:clj (:import [java.lang Math]))
  )
```

Parsing integers:

```
#?(:cljs
   (do
     (dotest
       (is= 0 (tpar/parse-int "0"))
       (is= 15 (tpar/parse-int "15"))
       (is= -5 (tpar/parse-int "-5"))
       (is= 99999 (tpar/parse-int "99999"))

       (throws? (tpar/parse-int ""))
       (throws? (tpar/parse-int "05"))
       (throws? (tpar/parse-int "123xxx"))
       (throws? (tpar/parse-int "12x3"))
       (throws? (tpar/parse-int "12.3"))
       (throws? (tpar/parse-int "xxx123")))
```

Parsing floats

```
     (dotest
       (is= 0 (tpar/parse-float "0"))
       (is= 0 (tpar/parse-float "0.0"))
       (is= 12.345 (tpar/parse-float "12.345"))
       (is= -5.1 (tpar/parse-float "-5.1"))
       (is= 42 (tpar/parse-float "42.0"))
       (is= 42 (tpar/parse-float "42"))
       (is= 123.45 (tpar/parse-float "1.2345e2"))

       (throws? (tpar/parse-float ""))
       (throws? (tpar/parse-float "xxx1.23"))
       (throws? (tpar/parse-float "1.23xxx"))
       (throws? (tpar/parse-float "1.2xx34")))
     ))
```

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try.